# Use of useSelector redux hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I made state in redux hooks I don't know how to import or useSelector the state I want

[image]

Here I am using the useSelector **Send to state** in **Login file**

```
function Login(props) {

var classes = useStyles();
var dispatch = useDispatch();

const { username, password } = useSelector((state) => ({
    ...state.combineReducers,
    ...state.userReducer,
}));
```

And that is **nav file**
And here I want to **get what's in the state**

```
function nav(props) {

    const { username } = useSelector((state) => ({
        ...state.combineReducers,
        ...state.userReducer,
    }));
```

**The error**

```
 Failed to compile.

./src/NAVBAR/nav.js
  Line 27:  React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "nav" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I have tried in many ways but it fails

Comment: Please avoid posting images and add a relevant code for creating a minimal reproducible example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `nav` is a **function** and not a **function-component**.

In your case, you may want to make a [`custom-hook`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook):

```
function useUsername() {
  const { userName } = useSelector(state => ({
    ...state.combineReducers,
    ...state.userReducer
  }));
  return { userName };
}

function Login(props) {
  const { userName } = useUsername();
  return <>...</>;
}
```

Note that if you want to make it a function component you need to return a `ReactElement` and be in scope with `React` import.

```
import React from 'react';

//        v Note that you must have an Upper-case for it to be a valid ReactElement
function Nav(props) {
  const { username } = useSelector(state => ({
    ...state.combineReducers,
    ...state.userReducer
  }));

  // return ReactElement
  return <>I'm some Element</>;
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem and found a simple solution.

```
const username = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.username)
```

so, we have taken specific username state from the reducer. This work for me:)